# Google Analytics - Interpreting sessions on a filtered view

Tags: session, google-analytics

Might be the wrong forum - Please redirect if you know the correct path - thanks.

In Google Analytics Sessions are attributed to the first page visited and are not meant to be used on the pageview level.

That makes sense to me on our full website view. 
However, I have someone using a view that filters to just show traffic to their section /explore. Does anyone know how I should be interpreting the sessions that are reported on this view? The person wanted to take the total sessions from that view and divide it into total sessions for the whole site view to get the acquisition traffic for her section. Besides being just an inefficient way to go about that - is she wrong? If anything, I think this would tell you the percentage of total traffic that section receives - but not necessarily acquisition or 'first touch' traffic, right? Because the filtered view means that any traffic there is treated as a first touch session and not compared to the larger site data. I think I've answered my own question already. But if anyone has any wisdom to add I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question because my point is very simple: you could just use the `previousPagePath` to know if the sessions in "her section" are real acquisitions or else are coming from other sections of your website. You are using the GA web app to look at this I guess; no idea on how to do this there. But if you are using other tools (e.g. I use R for the analysis) this calculation would be fairly easy... Hope it helps somehow.

Comment: Thanks - yeah I know my question was a little opaque. What I mean is there anything funny about how Google calculates these things that I should be aware of.I can think of lots of ways to sort of get the same information. But sometimes it isn't clear what goes into those numbers from Google. Like does making a view act like a 'mini website' so an entrance on that view is not an entrance to the site as a whole - but only that section, because that is all that is being reported in the view.